# Fuzzy noise in remote desktop view

Tags: rdp, vino

Enabled Remote Desktop from the settings menu. The RDP control is functional but the screen has fuzzy noise when viewed from the RDP client.
[image: Screenshot from Microsoft RDP Client on Android]

Configuration of the RDP is as follows:
[image]

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- X11 or Wayland(Issue exists on both)
- GNOME version: 42.9